# AngularJs 1.x upgrade, unexpected token : for a safe type

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular2-upgrade

I'm working on angularjs from 1 to 2 upgrade tutorial ([Angular 1 upgrade](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#switching-to-typescript)) and phonecat codebase example. After installing typescript and all mentioned dependencies adding a type **:boolean** for a function parameter input makes chrome fails the execution with "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" checkmarkFilterProvider consecutively is not created and fails the Provider injection into a component.

```
(function() {
    ///<reference path='../../../typings/index.d.ts' />
    'use strict';

    angular.
        module('core').
        filter('checkmark', function() {
            return function(input:boolean) {
                return input ? '\u2713' : '\u2718';
            };
        });
})();
```

npm run tsc -w command compiles .ts files and creates maps, however, browser execution fails. 
[image]

package.json

```
{
    "name": "angular-phonecat",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "A tutorial application for AngularJS",
    "repository": "https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {},
    "devDependencies": {
        "bower": "^1.7.7",
        "concurrently": "^2.1.0",
        "http-server": "^0.9.0",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
        "karma": "^0.13.22",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
        "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.7",
        "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
        "protractor": "^3.2.2",
        "shelljs": "^0.6.0",
        "tsc": "^1.20150623.0",
        "typescript": "^1.8.10",
        "typings": "^1.0.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "bower install",
        "prestart": "npm install",
        "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run http\" ",
        "tsc": "tsc",
        "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
        "typings": "typings",
        "http": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000 -c-1 ./app",
        "pretest": "npm install",
        "test": "karma start karma.conf.js",
        "test-single-run": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
        "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
        "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
        "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver",
        "protractor": "protractor e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js",
    }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "removeComments": false,
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

[image]

In the end *.ts source files are compiled in a project explorer but browser doesn't have them as @tadwork pointed out. What is my configuration missing out?

**Update**

To run the angular app I execute npm start script from package.json that theoretically should compile *.ts files and run http-server with the ./app as a server source (see package.json scripts -> start).

./app folder after script execution has compiled *.js and *.map.js files.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like the Typescript type annotations are getting injected into the browser without getting compiled so the types are still on the `input` parameter

`return function(input:` ***boolean*** `)`

Comment: You are right. Any advice how to possibly fix that?

Comment: this might be happening because the *.ts files are getting served, can you elaborate on how you are serving files?

Comment: I start http-server and targeting it to the ./app folder. Folder has compiled *.js files. There is an updated section in the question.

Comment: if you look at the compiled .js file in that folder does it have the boolean type? (not from the browser?)

Comment: Your questions led me to the answer. During upgrade ng1 to ng2 I have renamed *.js files to *.ts files, IDE renamed references too, references of the files in the index.html. After rollback of index.html everything works.